# How to filter an array with multiple values with linear time (ON)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filter

Is it possible to filter an array with multiple values with liner time O(N) the current example should be O(n^{2}), is it possible to run it faster? (In real world app I will have thousands of elements).

Could you point me out in the right direction?

```
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const filterBy = ['c', 'a'];

const r = data.filter(x => filterBy.includes(x));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: How about adding items to a hashmap in I guess O(n) (not sure though may be O(n*log(n)) and then creating an array from it in O(n).

Comment: Consider transforming `filterBy` array into a `Set`. Accessing `Set` is O(1) so overall the `.filter()` should take O(n).

Comment: ok cool, I found in the doc: The specification requires sets to be implemented "that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection". Therefore, it could be represented internally as a hash table (with O(1) lookup), a search tree (with O(log(N)) lookup), or any other data structure, as long as the complexity is better than O(N).

Comment: @Radex No there not Array based, but there not strictly O(1) either, but there not far off, and for most cases I'd say treating as O(1) would seem logical..

Comment: Notice also that if `filterBy` are always individual characters, and you are limited to some specific alphabet, then the size is bounded and quite small, so the time complexity is constant both theoretically and in practice, even with linear lookup. Still, I would use a map, set or a lookup array with the character's value as index.

Comment: thanks could you please write an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is possible.
you can use hash set which will provide you lookup of an element in O(1) (on average) instead of the filterBy array.
example:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const filterBy = ['c', 'a'];
const filterBySet = new Set(filterBy)
const r = data.filter(x => filterBySet.has(x));
console.log(r);
```